# Spark- check intersect of two string columns

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe below where `colA` and `colB` contain strings. I'm trying to check if `colB` contains any substring of values in `colA`. The vaules can contain `,` or space, but as long as any part of `colB`'s string has overlap with `colA`'s, it is a match. For example row 1 below has an overlap ("bc"), and row 2 does not.

I was thinking of splitting the values into arrays but the delimiters are not constant. Could someone please help to shed some light on how to do this? Many thanks for your help.

```
   +---+-------+-----------+
   | id|colA   | colB      |
   +---+-------+-----------+
   |  1|abc d  |  bc, z    |
   |  2|abcde  |  hj f     |
   +---+-------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split by using regex and then create a UDF function to check substrings.

Example:

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
data = [
    {"id": 1, "A": "abc d", "B": "bc, z, d"},
    {"id": 2, "A": "abc-d", "B": "acb, abc"},
    {"id": 3, "A": "abcde", "B": "hj f ab"},
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
split_regex = "((,)?\s|[-])"
df = df.withColumn("A", F.split(F.col("A"), split_regex))
df = df.withColumn("B", F.split(F.col("B"), split_regex))


def mapper(a, b):
    result = []
    for ele_b in b:
        for ele_a in a:
            if ele_b in ele_a:
                result.append(ele_b)
    return result


df = df.withColumn(
    "result", F.udf(mapper, ArrayType(StringType()))(F.col("A"), F.col("B"))
)
```

Result:

```
root
 |-- A: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- B: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- result: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

+--------+-----------+---+-------+                                              
|A       |B          |id |result |
+--------+-----------+---+-------+
|[abc, d]|[bc, z, d] |1  |[bc, d]|
|[abc, d]|[acb, abc] |2  |[abc]  |
|[abcde] |[hj, f, ab]|3  |[ab]   |
+--------+-----------+---+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom UDF to implement the intersect logic as below -

#### Data Preparation

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

import pandas as pd

data = {"id" :[1,2],
    "colA" : ["abc d","abcde"],
    "colB" : ["bc, z","hj f"]}
mypd = pd.DataFrame(data)

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(mypd)

sparkDF.show()

+---+-----+-----+
| id| colA| colB|
+---+-----+-----+
|  1|abc d|bc, z|
|  2|abcde| hj f|
+---+-----+-----+
```

#### UDF

```
def str_intersect(x,y):
    
    res = set(x) & set(y)
    if res:
        return ''.join(res)
    else:
        return None

str_intersect_udf = F.udf(lambda x,y:str_intersect(x,y),StringType())

sparkDF.withColumn('intersect',str_intersect_udf(F.col('colA'),F.col('colB'))).show()

+---+-----+-----+---------+
| id| colA| colB|intersect|
+---+-----+-----+---------+
|  1|abc d|bc, z|      bc |
|  2|abcde| hj f|     null|
+---+-----+-----+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not preserve the order of the string. Like for "abc d" and "cb, z" it will still return an intersect